# Extracting particular part of string amidst similar patterns (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, extract

I am attempting to create a query that will extract part of a string out of an amalgamation of comments left by users in our internal system for tracking complaints, developments, etc. about certain products. They problem is that the usernames are embedded in this amalgamated field all over the place. The criteria for extracting the string are:

- The username starts with "ET" each time
- The specific username I want to extract is the specific one preceding the "dc viewed" part of the string
- The idea is to report on the name of the first user of said "dc" team to acknowledge the request and return it to its own field.

So, in the example below, I would want to extract the second username ("Jane Doe") from the middle comment as that comment contains the "dc viewed" keyword. The difficulty in this is that all three comments are part of the same string and reside in one cell.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
2023-02-20 12:01 ET John Smith: @Department01 this product appears to have some damage on it. Can you check and see if you can verify this damage please? thank you---
,2023-02-20 12:10 ET Jane Doe: @John Smith Hello, I will look into this and get back to you as soon as possible. dc viewed---
,2023-02-20 13:04 ET Jane Doe: @John Smith​ Advised the product was in that condition when they picked it up.  Awaiting photos for proof.  As soon as I receive them I will let you know.---
```

Thus far I've just been messing around with string operators to try and suss out the logic, but as a relative newcomer to BigQuery SQL, I'm coming up against a wall. Research around the topic has had me giving a hard look to the SPLIT operator, but I'm unfamiliar with it and haven't had much success in messing around with it just yet, so I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is treating this as a regular expression problem.

The below would extract value after ET, but before the colon, where some text is followed by dc viewed.

```
regexp_extract(your_string, r"ET (.+):.+dc viewed")
```

Your specific example:

```
SELECT regexp_extract("""2023-02-20 12:01 ET John Smith: @Department01 this product appears to have some damage on it. Can you check and see if you can verify this damage please? thank you---
,2023-02-20 12:10 ET Jane Doe: @John Smith Hello, I will look into this and get back to you as soon as possible. dc viewed---
,2023-02-20 13:04 ET Jane Doe: @John Smith​ Advised the product was in that condition when they picked it up.  Awaiting photos for proof.  As soon as I receive them I will let you know.---""", 
r"ET (.+):.+dc viewed")
```

returns "Jane Doe"